# I can't npm run dev while deploying in Plesk a laravel project with vite

Tags: node.js, laravel, vite, plesk

I have a laravel project using Vite. 0 problems in local, php artisan serve -> npm run dev and the web is running perfectly.

The problem is in the deployment. I'm using Ionos as server and domain provider. I have another project using Laravel also but with Mix. Both projects use github for files transfer.

I followed the same steps, i deploy my website with git in Plesk, then I go to Laravel, `composer install`, `npm install`.

Then my website looks like this:

[image: vite manifest not found]

Then I go to Plesk again to Node.js and try to run `npm run build`:

[image: plesk dashboard]

And this is the error I get:

```
# npm run-script build
Process exited with non-zero exit code '1'

> build
> vite build


X [ERROR] Cannot read directory "../../../..": Access is denied.

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x7a pc=0xc4c942]

goroutine 19 [running]:
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/resolver.resolverQuery.tsConfigForDir(...)
    github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/resolver/resolver.go:977
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/resolver.resolverQuery.resolveWithoutSymlinks({0xc0000dc900?, 0xc000088410?, 0x0?, 0x3a?}, {0xc0000b01b0, 0x2b}, 0x0, {0xc00001e4c0, 0x3a})
    github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/resolver/resolver.go:828 +0x2a2
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/resolver.(*Resolver).Resolve(0xc0000dc900, {0xc0000b01b0, 0x2b}, {0xc00001e4c0, 0x3a}, 0x0)
    github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/resolver/resolver.go:577 +0x21ba
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.RunOnResolvePlugins({_, _, _}, _, {0xc0000a07e0, 0xc0000961f8, 0xc000096210, 0xc000092160, 0x4, 0xc000090300}, ...)
    github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:901 +0x352
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.(*scanner).addEntryPoints.func1(0x0, {{0xc00001e4c0, 0x3a}, {0x0, 0x0}, 0x1})
    github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:1653 +0x205
created by github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.(*scanner).addEntryPoints
    github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:1646 +0xc3a

failed to load config from C:\Inetpub\vhosts\carpoolingubu.es\httpdocs\vite.config.js
error during build:
Error: The service was stopped
    at C:\inetpub\vhosts\carpoolingubu.es\httpdocs\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1083:25
    at responseCallbacks. (C:\inetpub\vhosts\carpoolingubu.es\httpdocs\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:703:9)
    at Socket.afterClose (C:\inetpub\vhosts\carpoolingubu.es\httpdocs\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:693:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

Looks like somehow i cant get to vite.config.js

At first I didnt know what was the problem so I tried several thigs.

- Install Node.js extension in Plesk but didnt help, i got another error, 404.
- I updated the vite.config.js file but i figured out later that there's no point if the problem is that i cant access the file.
- I have deleted node_modules and run npm install again.
- I updated and reinstalled npm and composer in Plesk.

Anyone can help me? thank yo so much